# How do I apply a CheatEngine FOV fix to The Saboteur?

Tags: cheat-engine, the-saboteur

I have the Origin version of The Saboteur and would like to fix the FOV on my ultra-wide 32:9 monitor.

I have downloaded [this CheatEngine FOV fix](https://www.wsgf.org/dr/saboteur), but I wonder how to apply it. I can run CheatEngine, attach to the process, and load the CT file, but all it does is show two entries with question marks for "address" and "value" in the bottom area of CheatEngine (and the hotkeys <kbd>Num+</kbd> and <kbd>Num-</kbd> still don't work).

How do I activate this fix?

Answer (score 1):

I have found another hack which works with my Saboteur version:

https://chomikuj.pl/Jedrz/Prywatne/Gry/Mody+i+dodatki/The+Saboteur/FOV+Hack+for+The+Saboteur+v1.0

To download, click on the name, then "Pobierz" (2x).

It shows a small window with a slider which changes the FOV of a running Saboteur instance and also registers <kbd>Num+</kbd> and <kbd>Num-</kbd> as hotkeys to adjust it in game.